# filling data frame in python with loops

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am new in python and I am facing a problem that is driving me crazy :X
I have a list of Products as it follows filled with unique products

```
array(['NEG_00_04', 'NEG_04_08', 'NEG_08_12', 'NEG_12_16', 'NEG_16_20',
       'NEG_20_24', 'POS_00_04', 'POS_04_08', 'POS_08_12', 'POS_12_16',
       'POS_16_20', 'POS_20_24'], dtype=object)
```

I have done a function that will have as a result of a list of results with their respective date as it follows:
For example for product **resultado(waps_df1,'NEG_00_04')**

```
datum_von  Result
0   2017-10-10    1.10
1   2017-10-11    2.74
2   2017-10-12   3.96
3   2017-10-13   11.85
4   2017-10-14    7.83
5   2017-10-15   14.64
6   2017-10-16    5.11
7   2017-10-17   12.09
8   2017-10-18    8.47
9   2017-10-19    6.34
10  2017-10-20    7.68
11  2017-10-21   13.40
12  2017-10-22   25.53
13  2017-10-23    2.85
14  2017-10-24    5.80
15  2017-10-25    4.09
```

I created then this data frame

```
NEG_00_04  NEG_04_08  NEG_08_12  NEG_12_16  NEG_16_20  NEG_20_24  \
datum_von                                                                      
2017-10-10          1          1          1          1          1          1   
2017-10-10          1          1          1          1          1          1   
2017-10-10          1          1          1          1          1          1   
2017-10-10          1          1          1          1          1          1   
2017-10-10          1          1          1          1          1          1   
2017-10-10          1          1          1          1          1          1   
2017-10-10          1          1          1          1          1          1   
2017-10-10          1          1          1          1          1          1   
2017-10-10          1          1          1          1          1          1   
2017-10-10          1          1          1          1          1          1   
2017-10-10          1          1          1          1          1          1   
2017-10-10          1          1          1          1          1          1   
2017-10-11          1          1          1          1          1          1   
2017-10-11          1          1          1          1          1          1   
2017-10-11          1          1          1          1          1          1   
2017-10-11          1          1          1          1          1          1
```

**with the index od datum_von**

But now I am not sure how can I insert the results of every product correspondent to its date. I have the same dates in datum_von as index in my frame and also in my function so I wanna fill my date frame with the right correspondent result given by the following function

```
def resultado(waps_df1,prod):

    NEG_00_04_p =  waps_df1[waps_df1['produktname']== prod] #one prodkt NEG_00_04
    NEG_00_04_p = NEG_00_04_p.reset_index()
    NEG_00_04_p['Diff'] = -NEG_00_04_p['wap'].diff(-1) 
    NEG_00_04_p['Diff'].shift(+1).fillna(0)
    NEG_00_04_p['Diff'] = NEG_00_04_p['Diff'].shift(+1).fillna(0)
    NEG_00_04_p['Results'] = NEG_00_04_p['Diff'] + NEG_00_04_p['wap']
    NEG_00_04_p = NEG_00_04_p.drop('index', 1)
    NEG_00_04_p = NEG_00_04_p.drop('produktname', 1)
    NEG_00_04_p = NEG_00_04_p.drop('Diff', 1)
    NEG_00_04_p = NEG_00_04_p.drop('wap', 1)

    return NEG_00_04_p
```

The result of this function is like this but needs to be run for each product. this for the product NEG_OO_04

```
 datum_von  Results
0   2017-10-10     2.10
1   2017-10-11     4.74
2   2017-10-12    39.96
3   2017-10-13    11.85
4   2017-10-14     7.83
5   2017-10-15    14.64
6   2017-10-16     5.11
7   2017-10-17    12.09
8   2017-10-18     8.47
9   2017-10-19     6.34
10  2017-10-20     7.68
11  2017-10-21    13.40
12  2017-10-22    25.53
13  2017-10-23     2.85
14  2017-10-24     5.80
15  2017-10-25     4.09
```

***(Any ideas?) Probably cause I am not sure hot to manipulate data frame so well so I am not able to warp up my problem***

I have done this following code so far...

```
waps_df1 = get_marketdata(sql,'marketdata_db','prod6')
Products = waps_df1['produktname'].unique()
del waps_df1['datum_bis']
Days = waps_df1['datum_von'].unique()

###
indexed_df = waps_df1['datum_von']
columns = [Products]
df_ = pd.DataFrame(index = indexed_df, columns=columns)
df_ = df_.fillna(0)


dias = 0
x = 0
k = 0
i=0
y = df_.index.tolist()
for prod in Products:
    df_r = resultado(waps_df1,prod)
    if k == len(Products):
        break

    for dias in y:

        #df_.ix[dias,prod] = 1
        df_.ix[dias, prod] = df_r['Results'][i]
        i=i+1
    k=k+1
#df_.ix[dias,prod] = 1
```

Comment: *I have done a function...* ...please show such a function with input data so we can run the process. There is a very easy way to do what you need but we need a reproducible example. Also, show desired result as it is not immediately clear.

Comment: I think you want to pivot the data, using either `.pivot` or `.unstack`

Comment: I have edited! @Parfait

Comment: What is your desired results? Why so many duplicate date rows?

Comment: my desire result is to do a date frame composed by datum and columns by product with resultado inside for every cell yeah I need to get rid of repetition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the horizontal merge using [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) where you join all dataframes by the *datum_von* index. See adjustment to your function:

```
def resultado(df, prod):

    tmp = df[df['produktname'] == prod] # one prodkt NEG_00_04
    tmp = tmp.reset_index()
    tmp['Diff'] = -tmp['wap'].diff(-1) 
    tmp['Diff'].shift(+1).fillna(0)
    tmp['Diff'] = tmp['Diff'].shift(+1).fillna(0)
    tmp[prod] = tmp['Diff'] + tmp['wap']             # NAME EACH RESULTS COLUMN TO PRODUCT
    tmp = tmp.drop(['index', 'produktname', 'Diff', 'wap'], axis=1)        
    tmp = tmp.set_index('datum_von')                 # SET EACH DATAFRAME TO DATE INDEX

    return tmp

finaldf = pd.concat([resultado(waps_df1, p) for p in Products], axis=1)
```

Comment: OMG @Parfait Thank you so much! I so poorly tried! Your solution was perfect!!! You save my day, thank you!